# Apache finds non-existent files

Tags: apache

My web server has a peculiar behavior:

Let's say my website URL is http://my-domain.com, and I have an accessible file http://my-domain.com/blah.jpg in it.
For some reason I'm able to access the file using http://my-domain.com/blah.

It happens with any type of file.

Do you have any idea how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ths sounds like automatic content negotiation that apache supports with mod_negotiation, documented at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html. Please see the section labeled "Multiviews".

Comment: Thank you very much. It really was this strange module. I've simply disabled it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the reverse of this guy's problem:

http://www.webhostingtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-317269.html

If you give us a little more info on your Apache config, it might help...are you running any mods?  using mod_rewrite anywhere?  using a .htaccess file?